# DATES IN PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I have an issue when managing dates in PL/SQL.

I want to create a statement with the date as an input.

Here is the critical part of  my PL/SQL code :

```
stmt := 'INSERT INTO TMPWASMOVING (LOCATIONCODE, ITEMCODE, DATEBACK, TYPE)
         SELECT CODE, "bpart_id", 
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR("receive_dt",0,10),''yyyy-mm-dd'')
         - TO_DATE('||dst||',''yyyy-mm-dd''), ''Healthy'''
....
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
```

With dst a VARCHAR2 that I input using the following format '2015-09-01' for example. In that case I get an "input value not long enough for date format" error.

If I change my code to:

```
stmt := 'INSERT INTO TMPWASMOVING (LOCATIONCODE, ITEMCODE, DATEBACK, TYPE)
         SELECT CODE, "bpart_id",
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR("receive_dt",0,10),''yyyy-mm-dd'')
         - TO_DATE(''2015_09-01'',''yyyy-mm-dd''), ''Healthy'''
....
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
```

Then It is working perfectly fine.

Any advices / ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to add a pair of singe quotes: TO_DATE('''||dst||''',''yyyy-mm-dd'')?

Comment: See [Quoting string literal technique to avoid errors due to single-quotation marks in the string](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/31/quoting-string-literal-technique-to-avoid-erros-due-to-single-quotation-marks-in-the-string/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have omitted the quotation marks around the value of `dst` in your code - the following should work:

```
stmt := ' INSERT INTO TMPWASMOVING (LOCATIONCODE, ITEMCODE, DATEBACK, TYPE)
SELECT CODE,"bpart_id",TO_DATE(SUBSTR("receive_dt",0,10),''yyyy-mm-dd'')-     TO_DATE('''||dst||''',''yyyy-mm-dd''),''Healthy''
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you're doing this using dynamic SQL as there doesn't seem to be anything "dynamic" about it. You could accomplish the same using a static INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO TMPWASMOVING (LOCATIONCODE, ITEMCODE, DATEBACK, TYPE)
  SELECT CODE,
         "bpart_id",
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR("receive_dt", 0, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
           - TO_DATE(dst, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
         'Healthy');
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I agree with you. No reason to (ab)use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE here. +1

Comment: This is only a part of the code I used for testing but the name of table is a parameter as well

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass a date with USING clause.

```
DECLARE
  l_date DATE := to_date(dst, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
BEGIN
  stmt := ' INSERT INTO TMPWASMOVING (LOCATIONCODE, ITEMCODE, DATEBACK, TYPE)
            SELECT CODE,"bpart_id", TO_DATE(SUBSTR("receive_dt",0,10),''yyyy-mm-dd'') - :1,''Healthy''';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt USING l_date;
END;
```

PS. And before you got blind of quotes try to use quoting literals.
(highlighting here is poor, so try it in any Oracle client)

```
DECLARE
   s VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
   s := q'[Can't breathe 'cause it's beautiful.]';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(s);
END;
```

Comment: why you added substr ?

Comment: @Moudiz this question should be addressed to the author, but I think he's trying to cut a date from varchar field.

Comment: @diziag I mean in the second todate he didnt use substr he used instead TO_DATE(''2015_09-01''

Comment: Yes the date does not come in a really clean format and has to be cut.